# How to replace the loop in MsSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

For example

If I want to check in every day last week

```
select count(ID) from DB where date < "2019/07/01"
select count(ID) from DB where date < "2019/07/02"
select count(ID) from DB where date < "2019/07/03"
...
select count(ID) from DB where date < "2019/07/08"
```

like

```
0701 10
0702 15
0703 23
...
0707 45
```

How to do this without loop and one query?

Comment: Use a GROUP BY in your SQL

Comment: Using a GROUP BY would only return one result set instead of a different set for every day.   The Question does not state that this is desired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate the dates using a recursive CTE (or other method) and then run the query:

```
with dates as (
      select convert(date, '2019-07-01') as dte union all
      select dateadd(day, 1, dte)
      from dates
      where dte < '2019-07-08'
     )
select d.dte,
       (select count(*) from DB where DB.date < d.dte)
from dates d;
```

More efficient, though, is a cumulative sum:

```
select db.*
from (select date, count(*) as cnt, sum(count(*)) over (order by date) as running_cnt
      from db
      group by date
     ) d
where d.date >= '2019-07-01' and d.date < '2019-07-09';
```

Comment: You are missing a quote in the last line, but I can't edit as edits have to be at least 6 characters apparently.

Comment: Fixed the quote

Answer (score 2):

Are you just counting the number by day?

Something like

```
SELECT MONTH(date), DAY(date), COUNT(ID)
FROM DB
GROUP BY MONTH(date), DAY(date);
```

(assuming `date` is a `DATE` or `DATETIME`)

Answer (score 1):

Do it with window Count. `range between current row and current row` selects exactly this day rows.

```
select distinct date, count(1) over (order by Date) - count(1) over (order by Date range between current row and current row)
from DB 
where date between '2019-07-01' and '2019-07-08';
```

I assume `date` column is exactly DATE.